# How to create tables with geometry in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I need to create 2 tables with distinct geometry.

One needs to be a table that has point information. The other needs to be a table that has line information.

They do not need to be populated as this is just a test. They just need to have the geometry column.

The code so far is:

```
CREATE TABLE point

CREATE TABLE line
```

How to add the geometry into the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is:

```
create table points ( p POINT not null); 
create table lines ( l LINE not null);
```

Then inserts look like this:

```
insert into points (p) values (POINT(1.2, 123.1));
insert into lines (l) values (LINE(POINT(1.2, 123.1), POINT(-5, -123)));
```

You probably want to build indexes if you want to have some lookups on them. Also a primary key may be beneficial.

Comment: It created the table but doesn't have geometry column that I needed and forgot to ask. Also what do you mean by indexes? Also I thought it had something to do with Addgeometrycolumn. How can I add the geometry column?

Comment: the postgis docs for [AddGeometryColumn](http://postgis.net/docs/AddGeometryColumn.html) should give you what you need.

Comment: Do you have an example for `CIRCLE`?